# Create index to match a specific value in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, indexing, nosql

I want create and index to specific values to the fields `producto` and `color`

Something like:

```
db.ensayo.createIndex({producto:1:"myvalue",color:1:"myvalue2"});
```

It is posible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible. Also it looks really strange to do this. 
This index will perfectly answer your query:

```
db.ensayo.createIndex({
   producto:1,
   color:1
})
```

Comment: what if I only have those two columns and I have and index ti specific values?

Comment: @Ricardo can you please rephrase your question?

Comment: Sorry, I want improve the searchs when a document takes an specific value. The document has only two fields producto and color, then they only could take a known number of posible values like an Enum.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible now. I think you can use this solution.
You can set multiple indexes with their specific values.

```
db.ensayo.createIndex(
{
    "producto":1, 
    "color":1
},
{
    "unique" :true, 
    "partialFilterExpression" : {
        "producto":{ 
            "$eq": "myvalue"}, 
            "color": { "$eq": "myvalue2"}
        }
    }
);
```

Source: [mongodb docs partialFilterExpression](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-partial/)